Enforcing Auth Token for React app static asset fetching
I have a unique setup where I have a React App (which has the logic for user login and set auth token) and dynamically injecting Iframe in that app. This app assets are hosted at domain1.com.
Reason of injecting the Iframe due to the fact that assets are hosted at a different location with under same domain. Nginx has the logic to load those assets from a different location. domain1.com/path/index.html
Challenge is that all the requests to domain1.com/path/* needs to be signed by the auth token and in order to achieve that we need ability to intercept all traffic from the iframe including static assets request. I have tried Few things like overriding XMLHttpRequest call method, window fetch overriding but nothing is working out for me.
I need suggestion on how to tackle this problem. Possible solutions:

service workers but based on my research they are also not able to intercept traffic for static assets.
Adding some logic that overrides the static assets url, how to add that in webpack, that will be also something to investigate.

